# Chai assert if 2 arrays are equal no matter the order

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I need to make an assertion if 2 arrays are equal no mather in what order they are using chai.

I tried this approach but did not work:

```js
const arr1 = [{a:1,b:1}, {a:2,b:2}, {a:3,b:3}];
const arr2 = [{a:2,b:2}, {a:1,b:1}, {a:3,b:3}];
expect(arr1).to.deep.equal(arr2);
```

Comment: sort them before comparison?

Comment: check http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members

Comment: `[1,2,3]` does not equal `[3,2,1]`, so why should those arrays be considered equal?

Comment: @Cerbrus they have same elements, I am not saying they are equal, but in my case, it CAN BE considered equal

Comment: Exactly, in your case, so you'll need to write something for your case... Try Aaron's suggestion.

Comment: @RoggerFernandes did you try `members` ?

Answer (score 11):

```
expect([{a:1,b:1}, {a:2,b:2}, {a:3,b:3}]).to.have.deep.members([{a:2,b:2},{a:1,b:1},{a:3,b:3}]);
```

doc : http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members